# for-in (Objective-C Fast Enumeration) in the for-in

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'd like to add and remove some `UIView` all at once.
So, I made `NSArray` and insert `UIView` to it.
The problem is `NSArray.count` increase many times over, and the app get slow.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* customView1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* customView2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* customView3;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* viewsArray1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* viewsArray2;

- (void)setCustomView
{
    for (self.customView1 in self.viewsArray1)
    {
        if (self.customView1.frame.origin.x <= 100) 
        {
            self.customView2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.customView1.center.x + 50, self.customView1.center.y + 50, 50, 50)];
            [self.viewsArray2 addObject:self.customView2];
            for (self.customView2 in self.viewsArray) 
            {
                [self.view addSubview:self.customView2];
            }
        }
        else if (self.customView1.frame.origin.x > 100)
        {
            self.customView3 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.customView1.center.x + 100, self.customView1.center.y - 50, 50, 50)];
            [self.viewsArray2 addObject:self.customView3];
            for (self.customView3 in self.viewsArray2) 
            {
                [self.view addSubview:self.customView3];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)removeCustomView
{
    for (self.customView2 in self.viewsArray2)
    {
        [self.customView2 removeFromSuperview];
    }
    for (self.customView3 in self.viewsArray2)
    {
        [self.customView3 removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

[image]

Do you have any idea to simplify such a code?
Thank you.

Comment: all I see in your code there is "`addSubview`".  I don't see any code to remove subviews.

Comment: where do you remove any view at? you are just adding them only to the `viewArray2` and to your `view`, of course, the number of elements is only increasing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you need so many views and how your addition works, but here is how to remove all views from an array in one line

```
[self.viewsArray2 makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (self.customView2 in self.viewsArray2)
{
    [self.customView2 removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This is incorrect usage of fast enumeration. You should be using a temporary variable as the first parameter of the loop:

```
for (UIView *someView in self.viewsArray2)
{
    [someView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I don't even know what will happen if you pass `self.customView2` as the first parameter.